# When do a function's tangent lines touch every point?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a function $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}.$ Say that $f$ is big if every point of the plane lies on the graph of $f$ or a tangent line to $f.$ What can we say about big functions? Is there already a name for this property?

I've got arguments that show that all odd degree polynomials of degree larger than $1$ are big, and that no other polynomials are big, but I've got no idea what you could say about general functions with this property.

Comment: Is there anything specific you are curious about? Without a specific question, this might be closed as being too broad of a question or that it is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Clayton If I had to make it specific, I have a conjecture that this property is equivalent to $f''$ having a range of $\mathbb{R}$, but I'm curious if anything nice can be said.

Comment: I'd also be interested in knowing whether or not this property has a name--I've edited the question to include that.

Comment: Have you tried to prove that if $f$ is twice differentiable and $f'' > 0$ (or $f'' < 0$) then $f$ cannot be big? I am not sure this always holds, but would be a starting point fitting with my intuition.

Comment: I think your conjecture is not correct. Consider $f(x)=x + \sin x$. It's second derivative $f''(x)=-\sin x$ is bounded, but looking at the graph suggests that every point in the plane is covered by a tangent of $f$.